pytorch autograd on linear combination weights in the parameter space
I'm trying to multiply the parameters of one model (model A) by a scalar $\lambda$ to get another model (model B) which has the same architecture as A but different parameters. Then I feed a tensor into model B and get the output. I want to calculate the gradient of the output on $\lambda$ but the .backward() method doesn't work. Specifically, I try to run the following program:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class MyBaseModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyBaseModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(3, 8)
        self.act1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(8, 4)
        self.act2 = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(4, 5)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear3(self.act2(self.linear2(self.act1(self.linear1(x)))))

class WeightedSumModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WeightedSumModel, self).__init__()
        self.lambda_ = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(2.0))
        self.a = MyBaseModel()
        self.b = MyBaseModel()
    def forward(self, x):
        for para_b, para_a in zip(self.a.parameters(), self.b.parameters()):
            para_b.data = para_a.data * self.lambda_
        return self.b(x).sum()

input_tensor = torch.ones((2, 3))
weighted_sum_model = WeightedSumModel()
output_tensor = weighted_sum_model(input_tensor)
output_tensor.backward()

print(weighted_sum_model.lambda_.grad)

And the printed value is None.
I wonder how can I get the gradient of weighted_sum_model.lambda_ to optimize this parameter?
I tried various ways to get the parameters of weighted_sum_model.b but they all did't work. And I visualized the computation graph of WeightedSumModel, on which there is only b but not a and lambda.

If you'll check all gradients of para_b parameters, they all don't have gradient

Assigning tensors with values in place is not differentiable, you can do that with para_b.copy_(x), but pytorch won't allow it since para_b requires gradient, and if you do .detach() or torch.no_grad(), then self.lambda_ won't get a gradient

but if I check the gradients of weighted_sum_model.b like print(weighted_sum_model.b.linear2.bias.grad), I can get the gradients

Then how can I fix my problem?
